# Proving direct sums.

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-writing

Let $V$ be a vector space over $F$ and let $U$ and $W$ be subspaces such that $V=U+W.$ Prove that $V=U\oplus W$ if and only if $U\cap W=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$.

Attemp:

Suppose $V=U\oplus W$. By definition, $V=U+W$. If we take $v\in U\cap W$, then $0=v+(-v)$ so that $v\in U$ and $-v\in W$. Since $0$ must have a unique representation $u+w$ with $u\in U$ and $w\in W$, it follows that $v=0$. Hence, $U\cap W = \lbrace 0 \rbrace$.

Conversely, suppose $U\cap W=\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ and $V=U+W$. Suppose that $0=u+w$. Then $0=u+w$ implies that $u=-w\in W$. Hence, $u\in U\cap W$. Thus, $u=0$ which implies that $w=0$. Hence, $V=U\oplus W$.

Q.E.D

Is the above correct in content and structure? Any feedback is appreciated.

Comment: I would say both parts of the proof have problems. For the first one, why would $-w = u \Rightarrow u = 0, w = 0$ ? $V = U \oplus W$ means that each vector in $V$ can be written uniquely as a combination of vectors in $U$ and $W$. For the other direction, to see that $V = U + W$ is in fact a direct sum, you need to show that any vector $v \in V$ can be written uniquely, not just the $0$ vector.

Comment: I changed some things...Maybe for the forward direction I should use $v\in V$ not $v=0$.

Comment: It is still not correct. First part you only showed $u, w \in U \cap W$. Why would that implies $u = w = 0$ ? Second part, you only showed for any vector in $U \cap W$,  not any vector in $V$.

Comment: Isn't that what the backward direction is saying to prove. I.e choose something in the intersection...only option is the $0$ vector and show that it can be uniquely written as a linear combination of the form $v=u+w$ where $u\in U$ and $w\in W$?